# How do I remove/hide embed excerpts from posts

Tags: css, javascript, jquery

How can I remove post excerpt from internal links that are embed as posts to custom WordPress page.
https://prnt.sc/6e07tjSht5i7

I cant do it with classic CSS styling , I guess due to the iframe/embed post is called after the website/theme CSS is loaded.

I suppose I need some java/jQuery function to load after the embed posts/page load, but I'm not much a developer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove those excerpts with the following code in functions.php

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
```

Keep in mind that I'm using a theme "Newspaper" for other excerpt settings, which are not affected by the above code